# Gmail api returns results that are semantically different from those shown on gmail UI

Tags: python, email, gmail-api

I am using gmail api to provide a one stop search solution for all your SAAS applications but the results from Gmail UI are different from that provided by the UI.

The differences stated on google documentation for the API states that the only 2 difference it has are:

- The Gmail UI performs alias expansion which allows it to infer an account alias from a Google Workspace account. For example, suppose you have an account of myprimary@mycompany.net and your admin sets up an alias for that account of myalias@mycompany.net. If myalias@mycompany.net sends an email, but you search for "from: myprimary@mycompany.net)" the email sent by myalias@mycompany.net shows up as a search result the Gmail UI, but not in the API response.
- The Gmail UI allows users to perform thread-wide searches, but the API doesn't.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering#differences

but my cases are different like:

- query: gmail bill check

  gmail UI- gives email with subject "gmail bill check"

  gmail API- no results
- query: gmail invoice check

  gmail UI- gives email with subject "gmail bill check"

  gmail API- no results